# MVC4 Match against optional count of parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How should i register the default route to match against optional count of parameters. Like

`http://localhost:80/controler/action/value1/5`

```
public string MyAction(string param1, int param2) {
   //param1 == value1
   //param2 == 5
}
```

Comment: no, do not want to split it by my self, this looks nasty...

Comment: Unfortunately with asp.net's default routing I'm pretty sure this is your only option. Technically this could be possible with a custom Route attribute and/or custom ControllerActionInvoker. But with basic MVC I'm not sure this is possible. Somebody might prove me wrong though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are fine to specify many extra parameters using [UrlParameter.Optional](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlparameter%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) in the default route you can do something like:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{param1}/{param2}",
            defaults: new { controller = "home", action = "Index" , 
                param1 = UrlParameter.Optional, param2 = UrlParameter.Optional, }
        );
```

Side note: I would try to avoid such overly generic route and instead specify more targeted routes.